# Story about a female space traveler

Tags: story-identification, movie

Anyone know the name of this movie? It is about a female space traveler with narcissistic personality disorder who scams her way into a captain position.  However, her ruthless ways end up catching up to her, and when she is in trouble, she finds out she is left alone because none of the people she previously screwed over are willing to help her out.

Comment: What does NPD stand for?

Comment: @LAK Narcissistic personality disorder.

Comment: @user139959 - When did you watch this movie, and when do you think it was made?

Comment: I assume the movie was in English. Do you remember the nationality of the female captain? Asian, Hispanic? White? Black?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your question as it stands, is quite broad. Perhaps you can narrow it down a bit? When did you see this film? Where? Please take a look at [this list of sugestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) that might help you jog your memory.

Comment: The character of Dr. West in the remake TV series *Lost in Space* (2018-) is very like that, though the character is a little more complicated.

Comment: @NJohnny None of those words indicate nations.